# How to set breakpoints on ARM1176jzs?

Tags: arm, breakpoints, armv6

I want to program to set a break point  on ARM1176jzs. According to the manual, the breakpoint value/control registers are accessible only if DSCR[15:14] is equal to b10, meaning Monitor mode.
And according to the manual, DSCR can be written no matter what value DSCR[15:14] takes.
But actually I find that bit 15 of DSCR cannot be changed to one by a MCR instruction. Any one could help?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot write to DSCR using MCR instruction. I'm testing on a Cortex-R4. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No, I did not solve this problem. But the same code worked on the same CPU from another chipset vendor. So I just take it as limitations imposed by chipset vendors.

Comment: Were you able to figure out that the vendor disabled this feature by checking some flags? I checked DBGEN and it was assert in my case.

Comment: Actually I don not find any descriptions about limitations on the break point settings on the vendor's user manual. So I just assume that there could be limitations on usage of breakpoints for some vendor's chipset, probably due to anti-debug purposes.